# How do jets/airplane cold start?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, aerospace-engineering

If a jet starts in extreme cold, i.e cold starts, then the jet cannot power the heat exchangers to heat the fuel. Then how do they heat the fuel to start the jets?

Obviously you can't use batteries/inductive heating to heat the fuel. Most batteries don't work at the cold start temperatures (-50c or so). Even if you want to use exothermic chemicals to heat fuel, you need stored power to open valves.

Then how do they do it? Do they just insulate the tank and hope for the best? even if you insulate tank, you need power to pump fuel.

say its a kerosene +oil based jet. or jet fuel A.

Comment: Surface temperatures at or below -50C are going to be pretty rare for a turbine engine to be starting in. Most solutions to this type of problem would vary on a case by case basis.

Comment: Ok that is Mount Everest type elevation. The few places on earth where this is a problem most likely have their own procedure for keeping the fuel from jelling. It could be as simple as putting the craft in a hangar where it is only -30C. Sergei in Siberia just lights a bonfire underneath his Mig before he takes off.

Comment: but what if there is no external power. Are you recommending just insulation -like a hanger? you still need stored power to pump fuel right?

Comment: If your hypothetical situation is an aircraft with jelled fuel, no internal power, and no external power then you better start praying to the gods that looked after Shackleton because you are not going anywhere fast.

Comment: @Drew_J At cruising altitude for a jet aircraft air temperatures of -50C are normal, and they can go as low as -80C. Engine certification requires cold starts after soaking at -40C overnight - and typically the plane is covered in ice by that time. See https://www.popsci.com/climate-lab-indoor-weather-testing for pictures. You don't get jellied fuel (or even more damaging, jellied oil!) if you use the correct additives.

Comment: The basic method of starting jet engines designed for this sort of temperature range is to windmill the engine by blowing air into it. All the "power" for fuel pumping etc comes from mechanical drives from the main rotors. You only need to start one engine that way - then you have pienty of hot air available to start the others. Cold starting is irrelevant unless the *aircraft* also has anti-icing systems that will allow it to fly at such temperatures, of course - de-icing the aircraft on the ground before takeoff is only the first step!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while well-stated, belongs on aviation.SE

Comment: I agree with Carl on this one.  Although this isn't really a _bad_ engineering question, the aviation community here seems to really know their stuff.  Even considering the good answer here, I get the feeling aviation would provide a lot more references and resources.

Answer (score 4):

The basic method of starting jet engines designed for this sort of temperature range is to windmill the engine by blowing air into it. All the power for fuel pumping etc comes from mechanical drives from the main engine rotors, not from batteries.

The amount of electrical power needed to operate the engine igniter plugs is small, and there are battery chemistries that will work well enough (even if the maximum current is reduced) down to -40C.

You only need to start one engine that way - then you have plenty of hot air available to start the others. Cold starting is irrelevant unless the *aircraft* also has anti-icing systems that will allow it to fly at such temperatures, of course - de-icing the aircraft on the ground before takeoff is only the first step.

If the ground temperature is -40C, you obviously need to provide some heated accommodation for the crew and/or passengers, and that is enough to keep ground starting equipment warm as well. So far as the engine is concerned, a sudden transient temperature rise from say 0C to 1000C when it fires up is not much different from -40C to 1000C.

You can prevent jelling of fuel (and just as important, oil) with suitable additives.

Note that at passenger jet cruising altitudes, the air temperature is typically -50C in any case, and may go as low as -80C. Aircraft designed for surveillance, or search and rescue, may need special in-flight systems to work in those temperatures while loitering over the mission target, especially if some engines are shut down to save fuel.

For example the old UK Nimrod SAR planes (a modified version of the 1950s Comet passenger jet - now retired from service) might have two of the four engines shut down for 16 hours at altitude. The oil systems were modified so the oil flow path was through both engines on the same wing in sequence - the "shut down" engine continues to windmill, and therefore needs proper lubrication for the entire flight time.

Answer (score 0):

The can also be plugged into an external power source in need be, but their primary way of starting in extreme power situations is the backup power module, a gasoline generator stored in the rear of the plane.

Comment: wouldn't the gasoline also jelly up in the cold. how do you heat the gasoline to start the generator?

Comment: don't they have heated tanks... and don't they also use the fuel in the tanks as a heat sink for some systems...